# Elastic Search autocomplete with a secondary search order

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'm just working my way through Elastic Search and need some help with the autocomplete function.

Basically, I have the autocomplete function working, but I want to add a secondary sort order using my population field descending. However, when I insert a sort parameter to my query it gives me a 400 error message. Can you have a look at my mappings and query to see if they are set up correctly, and suggest what I need to do to make this work?

Many Thanks.

Mappings:

```
PUT /ff_search_locations2?pretty 
{
  "mappings": {
    "1": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "county": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "region": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "combined": {
          "type": "completion"
        },
        "city_lc": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "population": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My working query:

```
POST /ff_search_locations2/_suggest?pretty&pretty
{
  "1": {
    "prefix": "london",
    "completion": {
      "field": "combined"
    }
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

```
POST /ff_search_locations2/_suggest?pretty&pretty
{
  "1": {
    "prefix": "london",
    "completion": {
      "field": "combined"
    }

  },
  "sort": { "population": { "order": "desc" }}
}
```

and the returned error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "suggester with name [population] not supported"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "suggester with name [population] not supported"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The php code I'm using to generate the index:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$db = "my_db";
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "$db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM search_locations6 ORDER BY Population DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ii++;
    $i++;

    $data_array = array("city" => $row['city'],"county" => $row['county'],"region" => $row['region'],"country" => $row['country'],"url" => $row['url'],"combined" => $row['combined'],"city_lc" => $row['city_lc'],"population" => $row['Population'],"location" => array("lat" => $row['lat'],"lon" => $row['long']));

    //doing it in chunks, don't feel like changing heap sizes... etc.
    if($i < 10000)
    {
        $json_data = '{"index":{"_id":"'.$ii.'"}}';
        $json_data .= "\n";
        $json_data .= json_encode($data_array);
        $json_data .= "\n";
        file_put_contents('bulk.php', $json_data, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    else
    {
        exec('curl --fail --silent --show-error -XPOST \'localhost:9200/ff_search_locations2/1/_bulk?pretty&refresh\' --data-binary "@bulk.php"');
        unlink('bulk.php');
        unset($i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reference I should have found earlier [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort order is not supported with Suggesters query. The whole point of Suggesters is speed and adding sort to the mix will slow it down.

You can add `weight` to your query to improve the ranking but you cannot add a secondary sort index. If you are looking for a secondary sort I will suggest you can use `search`

EDIT: Looking at the indexing code, you can add `weight` for your `combined` field as the `population` field.

```
`$data_array = array("city" => $row['city'],"county" => $row['county'],"region" => $row['region'],"country" => $row['country'],"url" => $row['url'],"combined" => array("input" => $row['combined'], "weight" => $row['Population']),"city_lc" => $row['city_lc'],"population" => $row['Population'],"location" => array("lat" => $row['lat'],"lon" => $row['long']));`
```

Comment: It worked! if you could update your answer to say something like... Add your Population as your weight value in your completion type like so: `code`$data_array = array("city" => $row['city'],"county" => $row['county'],"region" => $row['region'],"country" => $row['country'],"url" => $row['url'],"combined" => array("input" => $row['combined'], "weight" => $row['Population']),"city_lc" => $row['city_lc'],"population" => $row['Population'],"location" => array("lat" => $row['lat'],"lon" => $row['long']));`code` then I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for putting the indexing code. Updated my answer.